# Append and remove characters before and after selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, window, selection

How can I get the characters *before* AND *after* the selected text, and then remove them? Or rather, if the selected text is within the characters, remove the surrounding characters, that way if there are any extra spaces the characters will still be removed.

For example, when double clicking on the text, it will select the text, but not the backticks before and after. I want to then remove those backticks.

I have it where I can add characters to the selection, but when only selecting the text and not the extra characters, I do not know how to remove them.

```js
$(document).on('click', 'button', function(e) {
  var target = $(this).attr('class');
  var str = window.getSelection();
  var text = str.toString().trim();
  var l = text.length;

  if ($(str.baseNode).closest('.input').length > 0) {
    switch (target) {
      case 'test':
        if ((text.charAt(0) != "`" && text.charAt(l - 1))) {
          var replacementText = "`" + text + "` ";
        } else {
          var rid = text.replace(/`/g, '');
          var replacementText = rid + ' ';
        }
        break;
    }
    formatSelection(str, text, replacementText);
  }
});

// format with buttons
function formatSelection(str, text, replacementText) {
  var sel, range;
  if (window.getSelection) {
    sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel.rangeCount) {
      range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
      range.deleteContents();
      range.insertNode(document.createTextNode(replacementText));
    }
  } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
    range = document.selection.createRange();

    range.text = replacementText;
  }
}
```

```css
.input {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
}

p {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="test">format</button>

<div contenteditable="true" class="input">
  `text`
</div>
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you want to do? is the problem the Uncaught TypeError that occurs in the code snippet? Lets say the input is `here is my 'code'`, where ' is `, do you want the program to replace the tick with something? If true what is that something? Or do you just want to extract the code part? Stack overflow does something along the lines of converting pairs of ticks to <code> </code> html tags, and styling them to have a specific background and font, is this what you want?

Comment: @Souleste If you want it to work with your example html, it is not just about removing the backticks from text. The text and the backticks are in different nodes (of type ```<p>```). You should first get a clear definition of what exactly to remove.

Comment: @Souleste Then you should update your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a different approach, using plain JS, see the comments in the snippet :

```js
var newText;
const elem = document.querySelector('.input');

document.querySelector('.test').addEventListener('click', e => {
  // get the content of the div
  const text = elem.innerHTML;

  // get the selection, in a string format, trim the white spaces
  const selection = window.getSelection();
  const selectionContent = selection.toString().trim();

  // if there's a word selected
  if (selectionContent) {
    const range = selection.getRangeAt(0)

    // selected line
    const line = range.startContainer.data;

    // indexes of the section
    const startIndex = range.startOffset;
    const endIndex = range.endOffset;

    // check if the backticks are included in the selection
    const backticksIncluded = selectionContent.match(/\`.*?\`/g) ? true : false;

    // check if the selected word is wrapped with backticks    
    const hasBackticks = backticksIncluded || "`" + selectionContent + "`" === line.slice(startIndex - 1, endIndex + 1);

    // check if the selection has a space in the end
    const space = selection.toString().endsWith(" ") ? " " : "";

    if (hasBackticks) {
      // if the selected text with backticks is found, 
      // replace it with the original selection ( without backticks)
      const startContent = line.slice(0, startIndex - (backticksIncluded ? 0 : 1));
      const endContent = line.slice(endIndex + (backticksIncluded ? 0 : 1));

      const newWord = backticksIncluded ? selectionContent.slice(1, -1) : selectionContent

      newText = startContent + newWord + space + endContent;
    } else {
      // if it doesn't have backticks, 
      // replace the selected text with the one having backticks
      const startContent = line.slice(0, startIndex);
      const endContent = line.slice(endIndex);

      newText = startContent + "`" + selectionContent + "`" + space + endContent;
    }

    // set the new content to the div
    elem.innerHTML = elem.innerHTML.replace(line.trim(), newText);
  }
});
```

```html
<button class="test">format</button>

<div contenteditable="true" class="input">hello `text` hello world</div>
```

Comment: This is nice, however when adding new lines and clicking the button, the div loses it's formatting, as in all of the lines are forced onto one line. Another issue is that when selecting the text and the backticks, it just adds more backticks, which is basically my issue in reverse.

Comment: I updated the answer, to use `innerHTML` instead of `textContent` to preserve the actual html inside the div

Comment: you don't need the backslashes there, but you do for the regex `const withBackticks = sel.match(/\*.*?\*/g) ? sel : \`*${sel}*\`;` and `newText = text.replace(withBackticks, sel.replace(/\*/g, ''));`

Comment: I realized that just after I posted the question... aha. I'm not familiar with ternarys nor am I an experienced regex user. Anyway, it is working brilliantly now! Thank you!

Comment: I've found another issue with this, select any `e` besides the `e` in "hello". Notice that when you try to format that selection, it finds the first string that matches, so if you try to format two of the same words or letters on the same line, it always formats the first matching string. I tried to fix this with "str.anchorNode" which returns that index where the selected string is, but I had no luck.

Comment: @Souleste , i just noticed that, it's fixed, check the updated answer, and if you want to use `*` , just replace the `\`` in the code

Comment: sweet, but when you put the second `hello` on a new line, it affects the first one :/

Comment: @Souleste , oops, didn't test lines breaks, check the updated answer

Comment: Thank you for being so quick to edit your answer and explain it too.